# react use context value inside a parent context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have 2 contexts in my `app.js` file:

```
function App() {
  return (
      <AuthContext>
        <ChildContext>
         <Template />
        </ChildContext>
     </AuthContext>
  );
}
```

when the user logs out I want to access a value inside `ChildContext` ,but `logout` function is inside `AuthContext`:

```
// inside AuthContext:
const myContext = useContext(ChildContext);
const logout = () => {
  // doing some stuff..
  //
  // here is the problem:
  console.log(myContext.some_value);
}
```

the error is:

```
cannot read property 'some_value' of undefined
```

that's because `ChildContext` is declared after `AuthContext`.
so how can I get to `some_value` inside `AuthContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React the [data flows down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down), so your options are:

1. `ChildContext` to be a parent of `AuthContext`.
2. Move `logout` function to its own context

```
function App() {
  const logout = () => {
    /*...*/
  };
  return (
    <LogoutContext value={logout}>
      <AuthContext>
        <ChildContext>
          <Template />
        </ChildContext>
      </AuthContext>
    </LogoutContext>
  );
}
```

Comment: with the help of your answer I kind of used option 2 and made a single component with a "/logout" route on it. and wrote logout logic inside that. thanks